# How to check MySQL cache lifetime?

Tags: mysql, lifetime

Normally, MySQL clears the cache automatically, when the tables are modified.

If there is any other query time limit which determine the lifetime, or generated cache could live for years, if the are no modifications ?

Comment: For me it's important to know for development, to avoid situations, when the cache is expired, to keep always high performance on important interfaces, to avoid pauses several seconds long for user, when he needs to wait the result of web-site.

Comment: Bill, you can't purge cache with `FLUSH QUERY CACHE`. It only defragments/compacts query cache.
According to MySQL ref. manual: > `FLUSH QUERY CACHE` does not remove any queries from the cache, unlike `FLUSH TABLES` or `RESET QUERY CACHE`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no TTL expiration policy for the MySQL query cache.

Of course all entries in the query cache go away when you restart the MySQL daemon.

And you can purge the query cache with [RESET QUERY CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reset.html).

If you need greater control over caching, you should probably use Memcached or some similar dedicating caching technology that you access directly from your application code.  In fact, more and more often I recommend to disable the MySQL query cache completely.

Comment: Thanks You very much for the answer, Bill. I could understand the positive use of Memcached + MySQL cache. Just wnated to say, what disabling the MySQL cache completly it's sounds too much cool as universal solution.

Comment: Universal solutions are easy, but not optimized for the case you need the most.